# Is it possible to do Network Security and Administration on Windows?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking

I am the 'wizz' of my flatshare. We have around 6-10 attached devices at any given time connected to a Netgear DGN1000 router.

By 'Network Security and Administration' I mean things like: monitoring bandwidth usage on a home router to each MAC address, monitoring packets sent/received between devices and viewing usage logs of each attached device.

I do NOT mean simple things like seeing the attached devices or MAC addresses as that can usually be done on the router's firmware.

The reason for this being that I suspect one of my flatmates is torrenting and severely lagging the network even though I told him not to!

Would it be possible to do this on a Windows machine or would I need a Unix distro?

Comment: Why not just block torrent traffic through your router?

Comment: opendns filtering makes this really easy....

Comment: @kobaltz because we all use it :P but when we're sleeping or at work. This guy however does it when we're home

Comment: @kobaltz FYI: "Mute" and "moot" [are not synonymous](http://grammarist.com/usage/moot-mute/).

Comment: I blame Google Keyboard autocorrect.

Comment: Optimizing QoS can make this a moot point.